# Analysing time complexity

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, upper-bound

Okay so we've been given an algorithm and asked to give an upper bound to its best and worst case

```
weirdSort(A,r,p)

if r < p

q = (r+p)/2
BubbleSort(A,r,q)
wierdSort(A,q+1,p)
Merge(A,r,q,p)
```

I'm not quiet sure how to do that.. this is my first time analysing time complexity and I'm quiet lost

I know that an upper bound for BubbleSort is $O(n^{2})$ for worst and $O(n)$ for best, and for Merge is $O(n)$ for both (Merge being the function that merges the arrays in MergeSort)

So for the worst case I have

$T\left(n\right)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+O\left(n^{2}\right)+O\left(n\right)\ ➜\ T\left(n\right)\ =\ T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+c_{1}n^{2}+c_{2}n$

and for the best case

$T\left(n\right)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+2O\left(n\right)\ ➜\ T\left(n\right)\ =\ T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+c_{1}n$

But now what? how do I handle $T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$? What are the steps I need to take in these types of questions? I feel like they've just thrown us in the water without really explaining how to solve stuff..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find an explicit formula for $T(n)$: Start by writing a few examples, such as $T(2)$, $T(4)$, etc.

Then, after you got some intuition on how $T(n)$ behaves, formulate it as a summation, and find a closed form for it. I will give the example of how to do it for the "best case" scenario:

### Examples

$T(2) = T(1) + c_1 \cdot 2$

$T(4) = T(2) + c_1 \cdot 4 = T(1) + c_1 \cdot 4 + c_1 \cdot 2 = T(1) + c_1 \cdot (4 + 2)$

$T(8) = T(4) + c_1 \cdot 8 = T(1) + c_1 \cdot 8 + c_1 \cdot 4 + c_1 \cdot 2 = T(1) + c_1 \cdot (8+4+2)$

### Opening recursion

And now (try for yourself) you can prove using induction that:

$T(n) = T(1) + c_1 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \log(n)\rfloor} \frac{n}{2^k}$

### Finding closed form

Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \log(n)\rfloor} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor} - 1}{\frac{1}{2}-1} = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{2}} \le 2$ Since it is the sum of a geometric progression.

Therefore, $T(n) = T(1) + c_1 \cdot n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \log(n)\rfloor} \frac{1}{2^k} \le T(1) + c_1 \cdot 2 \cdot n = O(n)$

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. :) Thanks you so much!

Comment: Hey why are is it 1/2^k * n and not just sigma 2^k? I don't get that part

Comment: At the first iteration of "unrolling" the recurrence, we get $n$, at the second iteration, another $n/2$, at the third, $n/4$, and at the $k$'th we get an additional $n/2^k$

Comment: Okay I guess I have to go over it a bit more. Regarding the induction, I was literally trying to prove it for 2-3 hours and I'm not even sure I'm trying to prove the correct thing.. can you elaborate a bit more on that step?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already done most of the work. Now it's just solving the recurrences $$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{2})+O(n)$$ and $$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{2})+O(n^2)$$
Both are pretty straightforward. The key is to keep substituting until you find a pattern, after which you analyze what will happen when the recursion bottoms out.
There are 2 common methods, namely the recursion tree method, and the substitution method. The former is more diagrammatic, while the latter involves more algebra.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcZw01FuH18) is a great video that solves your first recurrence (best case) while explaining both methods in detail.

Your second recurrence (worst case) has solutions [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19318/solution-to-recurrence-tn-tn-2-n2)

For more insight, [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture3.pdf) are some great lecture notes on solving recurrences.